# What does the functional elements of $L^0,L^1$ and $L^\infty$ look like?

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-calculus, finance, measurable-functions

In Mathematical finance (books; Mathematics of financial markets by robert J.elliot, Mathematic of arbitrage by freddy delbaen, Walter schachermayor), the following spaces are used for various things, $L^0(\Omega, \cal F,p, \mathbb{R}^n)$, $L^1(\Omega,\cal F,p,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and  $L^\infty(\Omega,\cal F,p,\mathbb{R}^n)$.

the following three from measure theory (book Measure integrale and probability by Marek Capinski) and wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space, I don't feel that I have issue understanding the following [What does Lebesgue measure space look like?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402320/what-does-lebesgue-measure-space-look-like)

$L^0$ representing the class of equivalent measurable spaces. which I understand.

$L^1$ representing the class of euivalent measurable space which are absolutely integrable and is finite.

$L^\infty$ representing the class of essentially bounded functions.

$L^0(\Omega,\cal F,p,\mathbb{R}^n)$-represents the equivalent measurable functions, in finance books this is used to denote the set of contingent claims.
from here I loss it what does the elements of the set (functional vector space) looks like.

To the me the element of $f \in L^0(\Omega,\cal F,p,\mathbb{R}^n)$ looks something like this:

$f:\Omega \times T \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, reasoning being that is $f(\omega, t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ represent the event and t the time, being an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ represent the discount gains process for T the terminal Gain. I know I am wrong in my understanding here, because the rest of the theories in the finance books doesnt make sense, can someone please explain what the elements of $L^0, L^1$ and $L^\infty$ look like.

The thing that confuse me is what does the domain and range of $f$ look like, like how are elements of $\omega \in \Omega$, $ A \in \cal F_t$, $t \in T$, $p$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ used?

Thanks in advance

Comment: for not finite measure spaces the notation $L^0$ is not well-suited. If you would take it literally, then it could mean the empty set, when you choose $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: measure with respect to p (probability) is finite